# Select multiple columns as JSON in a single query

Tags: sql-server, json

How can I combine several columns (of varying types, e.g. int, datetime, nvarchar) as a single JSON-formatted expression in a select query? For example, I have columns col1, col2 and want the query to return a single column where each row looks like this:

{col1: val1, col2: val2}

Can I use FOR JSON? I'm using SQL Server 2017, but the database I'm querying is 2008 (100) compatibility mode.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All the JSON syntax works regardless of compatibility level.

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.x(col1 char(4), col2 char(4));
GO
INSERT dbo.x(col1, col2) VALUES('val1','val2');
GO
SELECT * FROM dbo.x FOR JSON AUTO;
```

Results:

```
[{"col1":"val1","col2":"val2"}]
```

If you need it without the square brackets, you'll need to abstract it away so you can assign a column name to the JSON output:

```
;WITH x(y) AS (SELECT * FROM dbo.x FOR JSON AUTO)
  SELECT PARSENAME(y,1) FROM x;
```

Results:

```
{"col1":"val1","col2":"val2"}
```

And without quotes:

```
;WITH x(y) AS (SELECT * FROM dbo.x FOR JSON AUTO)
  SELECT REPLACE(PARSENAME(y,1),'"',' ') FROM x;
```

Results:

```
{ col1 : val1 , col2 : val2 }
```

And yes it works with all types:

```
DROP TABLE dbo.x;
GO
CREATE TABLE dbo.x(col1 char(4), col2 char(4), col3 int, col4 date);
GO
INSERT dbo.x(col1,col2,col3,col4) VALUES('val1', 'val2', 5, GETDATE());
GO
SELECT * FROM dbo.x FOR JSON AUTO;
```

Results:

```
[{"col1":"val1","col2":"val2","col3":5,"col4":"2019-02-11"}]
```

This assumes you don't have the closing square bracket `]` in your data. If you do, you'll either need to double it on extraction, before `FOR JSON` looks at it, or else use a more tedious method than `PARSENAME()` to removing the outer square brackets.

Comment: This is great, thank you. Can I also select other columns (not JSON) alongside the JSON one? It seems that the FOR AUTO applies to the whole query, right? I guess it would need to be some sort of join.